# How to fix an apt upgrade error

Tags: apt, dpkg

I could really use some help trying to figure out what to do with this, but I can't upgrade my server until it's fixed:

```bsh
sudo apt -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apport debconf
Suggested packages:
  apport-gtk | apport-kde debconf-doc debconf-utils libterm-readline-gnu-perl libgtk2-perl
  libnet-ldap-perl libqtgui4-perl libqtcore4-perl
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apport debconf
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 225 not upgraded.
31 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 257 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,096 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 debconf all 1.5.58ubuntu2 [136 kB]
Get:2 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 apport all 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.21 [121 kB]
Fetched 257 kB in 0s (16.3 MB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 163132 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../debconf_1.5.58ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 24, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/bin/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
  File "/usr/bin/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 24, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/bin/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
  File "/usr/bin/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/debconf_1.5.58ubuntu2_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 26, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/bin/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
  File "/usr/bin/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/debconf_1.5.58ubuntu2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

on an EC2 micro.
Any ideas?

UPDATE:
I appreciate the comment below from @FlorianDiesch. That is the correct assessment. I must have installed (poorly, I might add) a separate version of python that had tendrils in `/usr/bin/lib`. So I removed all of the offending files and cleaned up my `.bashrc`, which added to the confusion by exporting references to them. After all that was removed, I added the distro versions for 2.7 and 3.5 to `update-alternatives`:

```bsh
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.5 2
```

setting 2.7 as default.

Reinstalled pip:

```bsh
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

Then attended to apt:

```bsh
sudo apt -f install
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

And all is well with the world... except that in my frustration I nuked a config file that is going to take a second to restore. oh well. 
Thanks

Comment: `/usr/bin/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py`  looks strange. It seems like you've installed Python 2.7 manually or from some incompatible package and it's causing problems now. Try to remove it and install Python 2.7 from the official repository.

Comment: This is the correct answer. At some point I must have installed (poorly, I might add) a version of python that had tendrils in `/usr/bin/lib`. Once all of that was removed I made sure to add the distro versions to `update-alternatives`
`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1` and 
`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.5 2`
using 2.7 as default. `sudo apt -f install` then `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. And we're fixed... sorta. In my frustration I nuked a config file that'll take some time to restore. thx

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Reconfigure Package Database

Probably the database got corrupted while installing a package. Reconfiguring can fix the problem.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Option 2: Remove post info files of the troublesome package

Try removing the files associated with the package in question from `/var/lib/dpkg/info`.

From your terminal output, it looks like `debconf` is causing problems

```
ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/info | grep -i debconf
```

Now, just remove these files(or just move them to another location):

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/debconf.* /tmp
```